# file sql.gz give error 1064 when import in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to import a .sql.gz file that I exported before another server in phpmyadmin in this new phpmyadmin, the phpmyadmin version is the same, the sql is being imported the same way it was exported (GZIP), but the 1064 error and does not conclude

I was opening the .gz file in the text editor, it includes the delimiter - additional to see if it goes, but the result is the same

In the text editor, the .gzip file is not completely visible to the SQL text, after the thousand line is compressed, small sample text

> q@WG°LSÔµ
>   Ä]­0Scˆc»†8¼ëaˆ#üp¢–GwuyqdW—ïX¤^ù¡†Çumqd×…±Ä±]mXcˆãº†8¦ëaˆã93†£É`óóe’e/œ8º·àHÙ\
>   OìÛx¶2jò6o‚ŸgÛü¼Œ£ÕñEšÍ±ëU¦>Ç…ò‡ †æ!

I need to import this database in phpmyadmin and I can not, I exported another one to see if I could import, no, does phpmyadmin have any configuration that prevents importing the gzip file itself?

Comment: gzip files are compressed - you need to uncompress the file in order to see the plain text version of it

Answer (score 0):

extract and load sql:
`gzip -d filename`

or edit the phpmyadmin code to fix this permanently as [shown here](http://piwigo.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=151458).

Answer (score 0):

Use datatype `BLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB`, not `TEXT`.

Or, as already pointed out, `gunzip` first.